# Debugging, Testing & Deploying Android Library Projects

Tags: android

In general, how do I test & debug a plugin for a program that I didn't write? What I mean is, I am writing the library plugin, but I did not write the application that will reference it. I am building a library plugin project (specifically for the program "Locale"), but I don't see how to push it to my phone for testing.  And once the program is working, what will be different about deploying it than deploying a "regular" android app? Usually I can just grab the apk in the bin folder, but libraries just compile into jars.

By the way, am I building a shared or static library? How can I tell the difference between them? As I was searching for an answer to this question, I kept on seeing references to these different library types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing two different concepts: library and plugin. A library is reusable code that you can implement and use in other aplications, you test and debug the library when you compile, test and debug the app using the library.

A plugin, however, is just a "hook" with another app that extends it's functionality. A plugin can be part of a fully working application or can be a standalone without graphical interface, in any case it is an independent application with installable apk and it works just the same as any other app inside eclipse or your code editor of choice. Plugins are possible through permissions, other than that they are no different to any other app.

Comment: I see the error of my ways now. From the Locale developer page, there are sample downloads which depend on an Android library project. I (incorrectly) read that to say that my plugin had to also be compiled as a library project. Thanks for the help.